# iOS UITableViewCell de-selection issue

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am currently developing an app for a local vet so his clients can order products from their iPhone. I've run into this strange bug, namely I can't deselect TableViewCells in a dynamic table.

When I press a cell in my tableview it becomes selected like it normally would. However when I select a cell for the second time it won't deselect the first one. Even when I press an already selected cell the won't deselect.

Does anyone have any tips on what I'm doing wrong or what I should do to solve this problem?

**EDIT:**

Here's my code for selecting a table:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

hasCellSelected = YES;
cell1 = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell2 = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"medicineCell"
         forIndexPath:indexPath];
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
long row = [indexPath row];
cell2.medicineLabel.text = [_medicineArray objectAtIndex:row];
if (prevIndexPath && ![prevIndexPath isEqual:indexPath])
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
prevIndexPath = indexPath;



}
```

Comment: Without seeing what you've tried so far (i.e.: a *minimal* example) it's hard to know where you're going wrong. As such, I'd recommend updating your question with some of the code in question.

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple selection property set to YES.

Select your table , look at the right side of Xcode , the attributes Panel, there is a "allowMultipleSelection" property. Untick it.

Or place this in your viewDidLoad method

```
self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelection=NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deselect your current selected cell, You can use below code

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

If you want to deselect your previous selected cell, just update the above method to

```
NSIndexPath * prevIndexPath;

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    if (prevIndexPath && ![prevIndexPath isEqual:indexPath])
    {
        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    }

    prevIndexPath = indexPath;
}
```

Comment: I added your code but the table cells stay selected. The problem is dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"medicineCell" line, but i don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Don't we want to deselect the row at the prevIndexPath?